# How to set custom style for blueprintjs component?

Tags: blueprintjs

I am using blueprintjs with react and would like to customize blueprint component's size and color.

For example, I have a spinner, and would like to customize it size to 30px.

```
<Spinner className={'customSize'}/>
```

Which customSize is

```
.customSize{
   width: 30px;
}
```

However, it's not going to overwrite original size.
Is there a possible way to customize the size or color of spinner?

Thanks

Comment: try `.pt-spinner.customSize { width: 30px !important; }`

Comment: Yes, I am currently using !important. Just wondering if there is any better solution. But !important is actually good enough for my situation.

Comment: you'll need to write a more specific selector to avoid using `!important` here

Answer (score 1):

You can either write a more specific style than the one BlueprintJS supplies. They have quite strict opinions about how their toolkit is supposed to render.

They do support different sizes for the Spinner component though:

```
<Spinner size={SpinnerSize.LARGE} />
```

The options in the `SpinnerSize` constant are `SMALL`, `STANDARD` or `LARGE`. Those map to numbers, meaning the `size` prop expects a number. Why not try to give it our own number?

```
<Spinner size={137} />
```

You can learn more in [the docs here.](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/spinner)

Answer (score 0):

### For `<Spinner>` component

#### Size:

The `size` prop accepts a number including the following constants:

- `SpinnerSize.SMALL`
- `SpinnerSize.STANDARD`
- `SpinnerSize.LARGE`

> ```jsx
> <Spinner size={SpinnerSize.LARGE} />
> <Spinner size={128} />
> ```

#### Color:

As far as I know, there is no built-in component prop accepted to change the color. You can however customize the spinner's css classes:

> ```jsx
> // MyComponent.jsx
>
> import styles from './MyComponent.module.scss'
>
> <Spinner className={styles.mySpinner} />
> ```

> ```css
> /* MyComponent.module.css */
>
> .mySpinner :global(.bp4-spinner-track) { /* Unspinning part of circle */
>    stroke: #000;
> }
>
> .mySpinner :global(.bp4-spinner-head) { /* Spinning head */
>    stroke: #fff;
> }
> ```

---

### Other components

#### Size:

Some have the `large` prop, few ones have also the `small` prop.

> ```jsx
> <InputGroup small />
> <Switch large />
> ```

#### Color:

You can use CSS, but there are also some predefined color constants available in JS side: https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/colors

> ```jsx
> import { Colors } from "@blueprintjs/core"
>
> <Button style={{ color: Colors.BLUE3, background: Colors.LIME2}}/>
> ```